# A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, task, task-parallel-library

What does this mean and how to resolve it?

I am using  TPL tasks.

The whole error

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
>
> mscorlib

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If you create a Task, and you don't ever call `task.Wait()` or try to retrieve the result of a `Task<T>`, when the task is collected by the garbage collector, it will tear down your application during finalization.  For details, see MSDN's page on [Exception Handling in the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx).

The best option here is to "handle" the exception.  This can be done via a continuation - you can attach a continuation to the task, and log/swallow/etc the exception that occurs.  This provides a clean way to log task exceptions, and can be written as a simple extension method, ie:

```
public static void LogExceptions(this Task task)
{
    task.ContinueWith( t =>
    {
         var aggException = t.Exception.Flatten();
         foreach(var exception in aggException.InnerExceptions)
             LogException(exception);
    }, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

With the above, you can prevent any task from tearing down the app, and logging it, via:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 
   { 
       // Do your work...
   }).LogExceptions();
```

Alternatively, you can subscribe to the [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception.aspx) and handle it there.

Comment: For added entertainment, have a static stub method `Off` in a class named as the four-letter word of your choice, and use this for your catch-all continuations. Helps to combat some of the pent-up frustration from this particular exception.

Comment: actually this happened where i called a public static function inside of a tpl task. using try catch would solve this problem ? do i really need to create another task and wait it ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: A try catch inside of the function (the public static) that caught the exception would handle it.  The problem is that an exception is "bubbling up" to the task itself, and you're never waiting on the task to complete.  If you do, it'll fix it.

Comment: so i need to handle the problem inside public static function or inside tpl task where i call the public static function ? i mean covering the public static function call inside try catch block inside tpl task would solve problem ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Yes - You basically have to catch or handle the exception *somewhere*.  As long as you handle it somewhere, your core problem will go away.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the task could throw an exception before the call to ContinueWith is made?

Comment: @TimSylvester The framework will still map it through the continuation, even if it happens "before" the continuation is attached

Comment: @Reed Copsey Hi, having problems with yor approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831844/unobservedtaskexception-being-throw-but-it-is-handled-by-a-taskscheduler-unobser

Comment: Is it correct starting a task after logging of exception details? Baically continuation will log errors and restart tsk, or how it would be better to restart a task after failure?

Comment: @ReedCopsey When I try to use this method in my class, I get an error on the .LogExceptions(); portion. It says: System.Threading.Tasks.Task does not contain a definition for LogExceptions. Instead of defining LogExceptions() in my class, and then trying to reference it like this, should I just put the .ContinueWith(...) call on the Task instead?

Comment: @MasonG.Zhwiti Extension methods must be defined within a static class, and the namespace has to be included (`using TheNamespace;`)

Comment: Good practice is returning Task object from the method to allow another tasks to be chained via ContinueWith() etc.

Comment: Important note: This is only necessary for `.Net 4.0`. The exception handling was changed by default in `.net 4.5` to **not tear down the application**. See more in [Task Exception Handling in .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx)

Comment: I've tried this approach, but still have this exception in string 
`foreach (var exception in aggException.InnerExceptions)`

Comment: As an additional note, I was getting this exception was happening inside of an `async` method, but that method was not being called with an `await`.  Since it wasn't being awaited (improperly) the task failed but there was nothing holding on to it or observing it.

Answer (score 48):

Sure; it means a `Task` got finalized after being left to garbage collection, but the task itself failed. There are two fixes:

- handle the tasks fail directly (use `ContinueWith(...)` to subscribe, and check `.IsFaulted` and `.Exception` on the `Task` in the parameter)
- handle the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` event, and mark it observed (call `e.SetObserved()` after logging the error)

Comment: +1 - With one addition - if your continuation is doing nothing but checking the `IsFaulted`, you can use the `OnlyOnFaulted` continuation option and avoid the manual check...

Comment: actually this happened where i called a public static function inside of a tpl task. using try catch would solve this problem ? do i really need to create another task and wait it ? thanks

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `SetObserved` on `UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs` needs to be called.

Comment: A reminder that setting OnlyOnFaulted will mean that the OnlyOnFaulted task will be marked as Cancelled if the task it is attached to does not fault.  And Cancellation status comes with its own headaches.