# Task.ContinueWith and .wait(). ObjectDisposedException?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I use a pattern including tasks in C# where I do

```
Task.Factory.StartNew( .something... )
            .ContinueWith(t=> {
                                 try{ t.Wait() }
                                 catch(Exception ex) ...
                               });
```

if `something` forexample includes WCF code or other exception throwing stuff. That way Im sure that the tasks have been waited for I dont get those finalizer exceptions and I can consistently log error messages.

Recently I have seen that t.Wait() throws ObjectDisposed exception. Is my pattern wrong or should I keep the continue with only on `TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the *continuation* is firing, it is pretty obvious that it has completed (one way or another); there is no need to `Wait()` on something that has finished. Just check *how* it finished (completion, cancellation (`.IsCanceled`), exception (`.IsFaulted`)), and access the result (`.Result`) if appropriate.

The `ObjectDisposedException` sounds like the notorious WCF "feature", where-by the `Dispose()` in WCF can throw the above (which is annoying). There are various ways proposed to wrap WCF to handle this, but this is unrelated to the task API. WCF thus swallows the *actual* error, and surfaces `ObjectDisposedException`. There are several stackoverflow questions that address this.

Comment: So you are saying that if I just access t.Exception I can avoid the finalizer exception

Comment: "A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task " like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883052/a-tasks-exceptions-were-not-observed-either-by-waiting-on-the-task-or-accessi

Comment: @svrist and the end of that message is "or accessing its Exception property"; so yes - checking the exception **does** mark it observed (I've just verified this in a console exe, too)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following TaskContinuationOptions to see how your Task finished.

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(...)
(....)
 t.ContinueWith(task => (..Ran to Completion.. + task.Result),   TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);    
t.ContinueWith(task => (..Handle Exception .. + task.Exception),
       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
t.ContinueWith(task => (.. Was cancelled..),
       TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

Comment: Thanks svrist, I oversaw that in a hurry!