# Task Continuation (OnlyOnFaulted) still gets unobserved exception

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, continuations, unobserved-exception

I have a task with a continuation to handle errors:

```
var uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var loadTask = Task<List<OrderItemViewModel>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
       throw new Exception("derp");
});

var errorContinue = loadTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        MainViewModel.RemoveViewModel(this);
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, uiScheduler);
```

The continuation is hit, but a few seconds later I receive this error in the application:

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task
>   or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved
>   exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

Is this related to the uiScheduler? The solution to the similar question is basically what I'm doing    [A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883052/a-tasks-exceptions-were-not-observed-either-by-waiting-on-the-task-or-accessi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to actually handle (or at least observe) the exception:

```
var errorContinue = loadTask.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    // Observe/acknowledge the exception.  
    // You can use t.Wait(), which throws, or just grab the exception
    var exception = t.Exception; 
    MainViewModel.RemoveViewModel(this);
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, uiScheduler);
```

This is because of this line of the [documentation on exception handling in the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx):

> If you do not wait on a task that propagates an exception, or access its Exception property, the exception is escalated according to the .NET exception policy when the task is garbage-collected.

In your case, you have a continuation, but you never actually "wait on the exception" or access it's exception property.  The reason my answer (in the related question you posted) works is that I'm actually *using* the Exception property on the Task passed through the continuation.

Comment: Microsoft has changed the .NET exception policy since this answer was written.  See unobserved exceptions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh367887.aspx#core