# Garbage collection of Tasks in .Net

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

This may be a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer by myself so far.
I have a C#/.Net application which creates Task objects to perform parts of its work. If any exception are raising I log them as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883052/a-tasks-exceptions-were-not-observed-either-by-waiting-on-the-task-or-accessi/7883083#7883083), but what about Garbage Collecting?If I don't wait on those tasks, will it still clean their used resources?

Comment: Do you want the GC to delete these tasks? AFAIK, the C# GC don't do that...

Comment: I'd like to prevent memory leaks. I didn't know that the term was to Delete a task. I'd like it to clean up when the task is done, regardless of exceptions that might raise.

Answer (score 1):

This may be worth a read for how the GC works http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx

But, pretty much, if something somewhere has a reference to your Task object then the GC wont collect it.

Comment: Assuming that I don't - I create a new Task object locally, in a method, and only logs its exceptions if any (as described in the link in my question). In this case, will the GC collect the task and clean its resources?