# C# - What happens to a Task that throws an exception but the caller method is already done?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

What will happen (and why) if the following `if` statement is satisfied, and `Bar()` throws an exception?

```
    async Task Foo()
    {
        Task<object> myTask = Bar();
        if (condition)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            await myTask;
            // ....
            return;
        }
    }
```

Will the exception be caught? By who?

Comment: @Luaan Whoops, yes of course. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883052/a-tasks-exceptions-were-not-observed-either-by-waiting-on-the-task-or-accessi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Bar` throws an exception, it will be thrown right at the point where you call it.

However, if the `Task` that `Bar` returns wraps an exception, what happens depends on your version of .NET runtime - for .NET 4.0, it will bring down your entire process, because it eventually causes the exception to be thrown on a finalizer thread (or a thread-pool thread). For .NET 4.5+, the exception will be silently disposed of.

In any case, you don't want either. You should *always* explicitly handle any asynchronous exceptions that can be propagated in the asynchronous task. If you don't want to `await` the task in some branch of your code (say, you're pre-loading data you *think* you'll need, but don't), at least bind a continuation on the task to handle any possible exceptions gracefully.

Comment: I think you meant that for .NET 4.0 the exception bring down the entire process, and starting with .NET 4.5+, this has changed. Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/10217876.aspx

Answer (score 5):

No, the exception won't be caught.  You need to specifically add a continuation to the `Task` (note that when you `await` a task you're adding a continuation to it).